# Google analytics content experiments regex in URL

Tags: google-analytics, google-experiments

I need some solution to make url as on image shown. I think regular expressions don't work in that field, however it announced that regex works in google analytics.

[image]

Regards, Dmitry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex in Google Analytics is intended to be used in features that affect a broad range of pages or fields, like filters, advanced segments, etc.

The web page field from your screenshot is looking for a static URL.  The content experiments are designed to run variations on a single page.